# Visual studio successfully compiling MVC 4 project but controller shows some errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I initially had built a project in visual studio 2008 with .net 3.5 & mvc 2. I migrated it to visual studio 2010 with .net 4 & mvc 4. My project runs successfully without any errors. But when I open one controller, it shows error. eg Its not able to detect the Request or HttpContext object properties within a controller, it goes RED when I say Request.IsAuthenticated or any Request or HttpContent properties. Error says IsAuthenticated is not defined. Funny part is it compiles & runs perfectly. Little weird because when I create a fresh project in MVC 4 it does show such error. It is definitely a project level setting which needs to change. Please help.

Comment: I don't have a solution per se, but this is an intellisense problem, maybe uninstalling MVC2 to only keep MVC4 will solve this issue. I haven't tried it thus I can't guarantee that it will work.

Comment: Well that I cant do as my other apps are on MVC 2(in production). thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Resharper? We've had the same problem with it, with the first release of v7 not having this bug, but all others up to 7.1.1 suffering from it. If so, try and upgrade to see if it helps.

Otherwise Jetbrains claim clicking on Resharper | Options | Clear caches should help (although it didn't for us).